# Where to download decimals of Pi?

Tags: data-request

Where can I download decimals of Pi?

It must be in chunks so that I can download with a particular offset. It must be public domains, without any restrictions before download.

The site with most decimals wins.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: Unfortunately this website is not available anymore, see philshem's comments below for a potential? workaround.

---

This Japanese site has downloadable chunks up to 13x10^12:

Web site: http://piworld.calico.jp/estart.html

There are 130000 files (`pi-0001.txt`-`pi-130000.txt`), each chunk is a ZIP file about 55MB (so it's around 7.15TB in total, 15.34TB uncompressed).

No registration, agreement or anything needed.

Comment: as of 2016, the download is no longer available. https://web.archive.org/web/20161007132132/http://piworld.calico.jp/estart.html - and the current link is dead

Comment: seems some downloads are available on the archive: e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20150917224503/http://piworld.calico.jp/value/pi-100b/pi-0011.zip

Answer (score 5):

Based on the discussion [here](https://superuser.com/a/3822), it may be faster to calculate digits of pi rather than download them.

> I know you say you don't care, but I seriously suspect **your cpu can calculate them faster than your network card is capable of downloading them.**
>
> Given the last digit and the current state of the calculator used to generate it, the next digit can be found in constant time. It doesn't get progressively harder like finding the next prime does.

There are some tools to calculate on your own:

- [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/)
- [PiFast](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/PiProgram/pifast.html)
- [SuperPi](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=36)
- on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install pi`, and then `pi 100` to arbitrary precision ([source](https://superuser.com/a/495498) and [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/math/pi))

Comment: The said paragraph in that discussion comes with zero reference, and it only says "I seriously suspect".

Comment: 5 minutes to calculate 100m decimals on my reasonably new laptop (using `pi` package on non-virtual Ubuntu), 10 seconds to download the same as a 57MB file. Conclusion: calculating is 30 times slower than downloading.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I tried the download speed and it estimates 6 minutes for a file (maybe faster if you are in Japan). http://i.imgur.com/PXsYmPu.png It would be interesting to do proper benchmarking.

Comment: I downloaded the first 10 files (Germany, VDSL).  Average download time per file is 69.2s.  `pi` takes 7:33.14 total